# js private variable assigning

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm missing something in understanding how js works. here's the problem:

We declare a module like this:

```
ns.obj = function() {
    // declare private variables
    var test = 1, test1 = 2;

    // declare some private function
    var myFunc=function(){test=2};

        return{test:test, myFunc:myFunc};
}
```

Every time `myFunc` is called, as we are not declaring test inside the function js should assume we are referring to the private variable.

The returned object makes sure we have test and myFunc visible if we have the module. So calling ns.obj.test should give us 1 at first. And after we call myFunc should give us 2. But it`s always 1. Why that happens?

here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aXuwB/1/

Comment: I think your jsfiddle link is wrong

Comment: Yes, you are right, updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript overwriting a variable does not overwrite it anywhere else. You're effectively passing the number 1 in your return object; there is no reference to the `test` variable.

An option you have is returning a function. A function holds code and thus can hold a reference to a variable. Calling it would give you the variable: `test: function() { return test; }`.

Comment: the test variable is specified in his function

Comment: @badunk: Yes, but he's retuning just the number value. Overwriting `test` does not overwrite it in the returned object.

Comment: Watch the jsfiddle attached. Absolutely same code for array gives different result. If I call push it`s ok and I can see the result. If I reinit the array it doesn`t show up.

Comment: Calling `myFunc` does change the value of the private variable `test` to 2. But it does not change the value of `testObj.test`. That was initialized to `1` and is still `1` because nobody changed it. Arrays are reference objects; `testArr` is not an array. It is a reference to the array, and you put that same reference in `testObj.testArr`. Therefore, the same array is accessible by two different means, and changes to the array are therefore visible in two places. TL;DR: Read about the difference between reference types and value types.

Comment: thanks, Raymond, read it. But still not clear. When I make push it`s visible. When I make reassignment it`s not. Even if it`s a reference and I make it refer to a new instance, why isn`t it visible?

Comment: @Yaroslav Yakovlev: JavaScript doesn't really have references as in pointers that you can pass and overwrite. The only thing is that variables pointing to the same object will both receive updates to it. If you reassign variable A then B is still pointing to the old object, so updating A won't update B.

Answer (score 1):

```
var User = function () {
    var age = 0; // private
    this.incrementAge = function () { 
      return age++;
    }
    return this.incrementAge(); // closure
};

var firstUser = new User();
console.log('firstUser', firstUser.incrementAge());   // 1

var secondUser = new User();
console.log('secondUser', secondUser.incrementAge()); // 1
console.log('secondUser', secondUser.incrementAge()); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the fact that you are declaring a new `var test=1` everytime you execute the function.  To clarify, everytime you call `ns.obj()`, you will be reassigning a new test variable to 1 and then returning it in your object.  Thus, the value is always 1.

When you invoke the `myFunc` function, it will modify your private variable as you wanted, but you don't have a clean way to access the private variable (without resetting the value again).

Take a look at this and see if this demonstrates what you want:

```
var ns = {};
ns.obj = function(){
    var test = 1;
    this.myFunc = function(){
        test=2
    };
    this.getTest = function(){
        return test;
    }
}

var testObj = new ns.obj();
console.log(testObj.getTest());
testObj.myFunc()
console.log(testObj.getTest());
```

Comment: It`s executed once to initialize object literal. After that I`m just using it. So it`s not the case.

Comment: I am confused, when you say you are calling myFunc, it should return with 2 - but that function doesn't return any value

Comment: badunk, check the jsfiddle. It`s a module, function is called one time at start.